# Rewriting one subdirectory to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having great difficulty in rewriting my shop domain to my Magento subdirectory. Here's what I'm after:

> http://mydomain.com/shop/ -> /var/www/magento/
>
> http://mydomain.com/shop/anyFile.php -> /var/www/magento/anyFile.php

This is the ineffective rule I currently have in my /var/www/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop                
RewriteRule (.*) /magento/$1                     [L]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is the root directory of your site?

Comment: @AmineHajyoussef it is `/var/www/zend/`. I have another rule for that - below the one I described.

Comment: *"I'm having great difficulty in rewriting one subdirectory to another"* - Its befuddling how difficult Apache has made this task (or how difficult they have mad it to find a simple answer that works). Its almost like Apache is trying to make this difficult. I am amazed at how much time I have wasted on this task, and I am still looking for the right answer on these sites.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I replaced both lines with:

```
RewriteRule ^shop$         magento/index.php     [L]
RewriteRule ^shop(.*)$     magento$1             [L]
```

Comment: From where did you do this? From your Apache `httpd.conf`? From a `.htaccess` file? If so, where is it located in relation to the rules?

Comment: @jww This was a long while ago! But from looking at the question it looks like this was placed in a .htaccess file - sorry I can't be more specific.